# Android 12: Tracker apps with accessibility shown as floating icon in home screen

Tags: android, accessibility, tracker, android-12

Tracker apps with accessibility feature is shown as permanent floating icon on the home screen when I updated my phone OS to Android 12 on Google Pixel 3A. It can't be removed without disabling accessibility. Is there anyway to not show the icon without disabling any app feature?

Comment: could you share a screen shot? is it a question about your app? (if not it doesn't belong to SO) my apps running some `AccessibilityService`s just running them, no additional icons anywhere

Comment: @snachmsm, it's not about my app. its the new feature of Android 12 OS. Will update with a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Hello there I had the same issue and I have the answer now:

1. Go to accessibility
2. Go to the app(s) which is shown on your side
3. there is one option to disable the app and underneath is an option to disable the little Icon.

The feature is to quickly enable or disable these apps. For example you can quickly disable your password manager or anything like this.

Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks  will check it out.